# How different would be these two compile-time Factorial functions in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming, consteval

Following [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68371252/why-is-there-such-a-massive-difference-in-compile-time-between-consteval-constex) link, I came up to this question.

I'm trying to understand how different would be the targeting the following two compile-time functions by a `C++20` compiler.

```
consteval int Factorial(int n) 
{
    int result = 1;
    while (n > 1) 
        result *= n--;
    return result;
}
```

and what we had in `C++11` in case being used by `C++20`

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial {
     static constexpr int value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value;
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> {
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};
```

Is it similar when compiler tries to, for instance, do `Factorial(10)` and `Factorial<10>::value` in terms of using `compiler depth`, `creating stack frame (if there would be any for consteval int Factorial(int n))` and anything else?

Comment: Here, the class template version can't make use of prior instantiations, which it can in the Ackermann calculation in the link you shared, so I don't think the template version has an automatic benefit in this case.

Comment: Note that all such factorials are very limited bordering on useless for anything practical. The int is typically 32 bit so 12! (479,001,600) typically fits into it but 13! (6,227,020,800) does not.